# Web scraping on react native iOS app using recurring background service

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How do you get a background service running a web view in iOS using react- native?

I need to gather user history from myactivity.google.com on iOS using a React Native app.

I am able to do this on Android by loading the webpage in the background and scrape the data, can this be done in iOS too?

Comment: Just to be curious and sorry for the question. Why can't you use .NET technology in windows? Are you trying to do illegal things? ahaha xD

Comment: @Aspicas Good question :') There is a different requirement to showcase the user data on dashboard. Please let me know if you have tried anything like this :)